# Mysql - case statement updating all values not just matching ids

Tags: mysql

I have a case statement updating multiple column and rows at the same time but for some reason it updates all the rows and columns even when there is no values entered.

```
UPDATE price SET item = CASE id 
    WHEN 18 THEN 'cvbcvbcvb' 
END, 
description = CASE id 
    WHEN 17 THEN 'cvbcv' 
END, 
price = CASE id 
    WHEN 19 THEN '222' 
END
WHERE id IN (17, 18, 19);
```

I have noticed that if a column is not updated the no value for that column changes, so for example, if omitted the column description then none of the values in description are lost

any ideas?

EDIT i am using PHP to collect the data and the amount of updates will vary based on user input sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data, the results you are getting, and your desired results?

Comment: it varies TBH from page to page and what the user inputs.  here i have a table with 4 columns id, item, description and price. i want to only update the values the user inputs from the form. i use a array and a loop to build the sql statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case wont't help you here. Try this instead.

```
UPDATE price SET
  item = if(id = 18, 'cvbcvbcvb', item), 
  description = if(id = 17, 'cvbcv', description), 
  price = if(id = 19, '222', price)
WHERE id IN (17, 18, 19);
```

**UPDATE** addressing the comments:
Apparently it has to be `CASE`.
Try this, please:

```
UPDATE price SET
  item = CASE id WHEN 18 THEN 'cvbcvbcvb' ELSE item END,
  description = CASE id WHEN 17 THEN 'cvbcv' ELSE description END,
  price = CASE id WHEN 19 THEN '222' ELSE price END
WHERE id IN (17, 18, 19);
```

Using CASE does not depend on it being in a SELECT, it's just an operator - you can use it in SELECT, ON or USING in FROM, WHERE, HAVING, ... pretty much anywhere.

I don't know about that syntax error, please update your code.

Comment: thats ok but what if i have multiple updates, say description has 4 values that need updating and item has 2  and price has 3, wont this get complicated?

Comment: then you only have to put the field itself in the `ELSE` of that case.

Comment: I prefer IF for your example because it's shorter, but you can use CASE. You only have to add ELSE for the original value if no other value is set.

Comment: what just the word ELSE and is that before END?

Comment: yes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: that doesnt help there talking about select statements there and just the world else throws a syntax error

Comment: thank you thou in my defence you initial explanation wasn't very clear